# PHP Session Array Value keeps showing as "Array"

Tags: php

When sending data from a form to a second page, the value of the session is always with the name "Array" insteed of the expected number.

The data should get displayed in a table, but insteed of example 1, 2, 3 , 4 i get : Array, Array, Array.
(A 2-Dimensional Table is used)

Is the following code below a proper way to "call" upon the stored values on the 2nd page from the array ?

```
$test1 = $_SESSION["table"][0];
$test2 = $_SESSION["table"][1];
$test3 = $_SESSION["table"][2];
$test4 = $_SESSION["table"][3];
$test5 = $_SESSION["table"][4];
```

What exactly is this, and how can i fix this?
Is it some sort of override that needs to happen?

Best Regards.

Comment: You should `print_r` those to see what's there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need any sort of override. The script is printing "Array" rather than a value, because you're trying to print to the screen a whole array, rather than a value within an array for example:

```
$some_array = array('0','1','2','3');

echo $some_array; //this will print out "Array"

echo $some_array[0]; //this will print "0"

print_r($some_array); //this will list all values within the array. Try it out!
```

`print_r()` is not useful for production code, because its ugly; however, for testing purposes it can keep you from pulling your hair out over nested arrays.

It's perfectly fine to access elements in your array by index: `$some_array[2]`

if you want it in a table you might do something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    for($i = 0 ; $i < count($some_array) ; $i++) {
        echo '<td>'.$some_array[$i].'</td>';
    }
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'll have to nitpick. PHP has nested arrays, not really multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 6):

As noted, try

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";
```

That should show you what's in the session array.

Comment: What does the output from the print_r show?  That may help us with finding the issue.

Comment: `print_r` is not to put into your page (as stated by jordanstephens in his answer).  It's for debugging, so we can see the structure of the array.

Answer (score 0):

A 2-dimensional table is just an array of arrays.

So, by pulling out `$_SESSION["table"][0]`, you're pulling out an array that represents the first row of the table.

If you want a specific value from that table, you need to pass the second index, too. i.e. `$_SESSION["table"][0][0]`

Or you could just be lazy and do `$table = $_SESSION["table"];` at which point `$table` would be your normal table again.

Answer (score 0):

A nice way ...

```
<?php
    foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br>";
    }
?>
```